# public static int getCoins(int[][] map, int row, int col) method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, 2d

hey guys so i am trying to solve this problem I am makeing a java method that takes in a 2D array and 2 ints to dictate a starting position  of a coin gatherer in the array.   The gatherer    is  greedy  and lazy    when    deciding    to  which   adjacent    location    (either up, down,   left,   right)  to  move next.  It’s    greedy  because it  moves   to  the location
with the    highest number  of  coins;  and it’s    lazy    because it  will    stop    moving  if  no  adjacent    location    increases   its coin    treasure.   If  several adjacent    locations had   the same    highest number  of  coins,  the 
gatherer    will    choose  to  move    to  the highest in  a   clockwise   fashion (up,    right,  down,   left).  Diagonal locations  are not considered  adjacent.   The gatherer    empties the coins   from    any location    it  visits. Lastly, 
the method  returns the coins   acquired    up  to  the point   when    the gatherer    doesn't move    anymore. this is what i have so far but the issue i am running into is the when running a junit test it gets a out of bounds error with the way i am checking the values of the surrounding values. any help fixing this would be appreciated.

```
    public class Program3 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
    public static int getCoins(int[][] map, int row, int col)
    {
    int cointotal = map[row][col];
    int[] numbers = new int[4];
    int big = 0;
    int a = map[row-1][col];
    int b = map[row-1][col-1];
    int c = map[row][col-1];
    int d = map[row+1][col];
    while(a > cointotal || b > cointotal || c > cointotal || d > cointotal)
    {
    numbers[0] = a;
    numbers[1] = b;
    numbers[2] = c;
    numbers[3] = d;
    big = findLargest(numbers);
    cointotal = cointotal + big;

    a = map[row-1][col];
    b = map[row-1][col-1];
    c = map[row][col-1];
    d = map[row+1][col];

   if(numbers[0] == big)
   {
       row = row -1;
       col = col;
   }
   if(numbers[1] == big)
   {
       row = row - 1;
       col = col - 1;         
   }
   if(numbers[2] == big)
   {
       row = row;
       col = col - 1;     
   }
   if(numbers[3] == big)
   {
       row = row + 1;
       col = col; 
   }
}

    return cointotal;
    }
    public static int findLargest(int[] numbers){  
    int largest = numbers[0];  
     for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){  
        if(numbers[i] > largest){  
            largest = numbers[i];  
            }    
    }  
    return largest;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers array has size 3, so it goes from 0 to 2.

```
int[] numbers = new int[3];
```

But you are accessing 4th element

```
    numbers[0] = a;
    numbers[1] = b;
    numbers[2] = c;
    numbers[3] = d; //OutOfBound
```

Try

```
 int[] numbers = new int[4];
```

**Edit:**

I advice, before accessing your array validate the indices.

```
int rowLength = map.length;
int columnLength = (rowLength==0)0:map[0].length;

//other code
boolean verify(int x, int y){
   return x < rowLength && y < columnLength;
}

//then you can do something like this
int a = verify(row-1,col)? map[row-1][col]: a; //don't change if the index is outOfBounds
```

Comment: still getting out of bounds exceptions from the 2D array that serves as the map for the gatherer. cant think of a way to check for the surrounding values, without running into this prob.